# Node js+Laravel +python communication for hybrid app development

Tags: python, node.js, laravel

I need to develop a hybrid app with node js for user authentication and laravel for app functionalities and python for complex computations.So every request from the front should reach node js and from there request will be diverted to corresponding platform(laravel or pyhton).Node js should act as a middleware for this.How can it be possible to communicate between these multiple platforms and is any architecture available for these kind of hybrid app development.It can be possible to communicate using REST apis,But how the authentication can be done.

Comment: which system do you going to build with this type of hybrid development ?

Answer (score 1):

in **NodeJS** : you can use ExpressJS http://expressjs.com/ framework for REST API

in **Python** : you can use Django framework https://www.djangoproject.com/ for REST API

you can send `AJAX request` from Frontend built with `Laravel` , to your NodeJS server , and after validating login , you can send user authentication status like below :

login failed :

```
{ 
  status:"error",
  message:"Login Failed , Invalid Credentials"
}
```

for login successfull :

```
{
    status:"success",
    message:"Login Successful",
    user:{ 
       id:"",
       name:"",
       email:"",
       ...
    }
 }
```

but now you have to login this user to your Laravel System , so

> you need to develop custom functions for Login , Logout and Register.

But this is not correct way , because it becomes Time-consuming , instead I suggest you to use Laravel's built in **Auth System** using just a single command `php artisan make:auth`

I also suggest you to choose either NodeJS or Laravel for backend , because both are powerful in its place .

in NodeJS various NPM packages available :

expressjs : http://expressjs.com/

passport : http://www.passportjs.org/

body-parser : https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

multer : https://github.com/expressjs/multer

ejs : http://ejs.co/

async : https://caolan.github.io/async/

request : https://github.com/request/request

socket-io : https://socket.io/

lodash : https://lodash.com/docs/

moment : http://momentjs.com/

nodemailer : https://nodemailer.com/about/

node-mysql : https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

mongoose : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/

redis : http://redis.js.org/

in Laravel you can use different packages using composer

Socialite : https://github.com/laravel/socialite

Passport : https://github.com/laravel/passport

PHP mailer : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Carbon : http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Pusher : https://pusher.com/

etc...Laravel provides lots of features built in .

if your system has more number of users than it is better to use NodeJS as Backend.

Finally Choice is yours as per your requirement . you can do communication between these apps by creating REST API end points and calling them using AJAX from frontend.